# o CEP é um ID único no Brasil?

Tags: banco-de-dados, cep, web-service

Eu possuo a base oficial de CEPs do Brasil, a e-DNE, vendida pelos correios.

Preciso criar um novo banco a partir dela, e gostaria de saber se posso usar o valor do CEP como identificador único do meu DB.

Como existem localidades que usam o mesmo cep para vários endereço, gostaria de saber como identificar unicamente esses locais.

Comment: Poem vários endereços nisso. Tem lugar que é um CEP para a cidade inteira.

Comment: Identificador único do quê? O que você considera um "local"? O que sei é que o CEP pode ser de alguns quarteirões ou de um bairro inteiro (talvez até de cidades pequenas inteiras). Então se precisar identificar algo mais específico que isso, não, não serve.

Comment: Vale lembrar que CEP's mudam com certa frequência. Recentemente minha rua ganhou mais um CEP, e o CEP daonde moro mudou. Ok, é raro - em 27 anos, meu endereço só mudou de CEP duas vezes. Mas leve isso em consideração.

Comment: Olha, o CEP em si é único no sentido que não existe outro CEP com a mesma numeração porém eu teria receio de usa-lo como PK. Poste seu schema para que possamos contextualizar e dar uma resposta mais precisa

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Vamos voltar um pouco a teoria das chaves primárias, devemos fazer algumas análises:
Regras básicas para chaves primárias:

1. NÂO PODE haver duas ocorrências de uma mesma entidade com o mesmo
   conteúdo na Chave Primária
2. A chave primária não pode ser composta por atributo opcional , ou
   seja , atributo que aceite nulo.
3. Os atributos identificadores devem ser o conjunto mínimo que pode
   identificar cada instância de um entidade.
4. Não devem ser usadas chaves externas. (Atributos sobre os quais você
   não tem controle. Ex: CPF, CNPJ)
5. Cada atributo identificador da chave deve possui um tamanho reduzido
   Não deve conter informação volátil.

Vamos partir do número 4, onde CEP é uma chave externa, ou seja, caso seja incluído algum número ou haja alguma modificação, como você agiria em casos como este? Lembrando que recentemente na cidade de São Paulo houve a alteração no número de telefone. Mudanças como essas em uma PK(chave primária) causaria muitos problemas. A idéia de seguir as normalizações é garantir a estabilidade do seu banco de dados junto ao ACID(Atomicidade, Consistência, Isolamento e Durabilidade).

Você até poderia facilitar a procura usando o número do cep como INDEX, isso ajudaria, porém, nesse caso o melhor é manter a PK com um ID de auto-incremento mesmo.

Comment: bela explicação.

Answer (score 4):

Chegando 1 ano depois, mas a intensão aqui é deixar registrado o link para o 
[conceito de "coisa geográfica designada pelo CEP"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal#Entidades_geogr.C3.A1ficas_designadas_pelo_CEP)... Isso leva a 2 respostas.

Somente depois de se ter clareza do objeto, da coisa que foi identificada pelo CEP, é que faz sentido em se perguntar por exemplo se a coisa mudou, ou, mais importante, se dois CEPs não estariam apontando para a mesma coisa: se dois CEPs apontam para a mesma coisa ele não é único, ou seja, não pode ser considerado um [identificador único](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier).

A "coisa" típica apontada pelos CEPs até 1992 era uma cidade ou sub-região de cidade, apelidada pelos Correios de "Divisor de Sub-Setor". Havia até um mapa [mapa das regiões de CEP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:MAPA_DAS_REGI%C3%95ES_DE_CEP.JPG), que hoje ainda vale para se mapear os *CEPs genéricos*, aqueles na forma `XXXXX-000` (sufixo zero)... **Resposta-1**: *CEPs genéricos*  são sempre únicos, designando cada qual a sua região no mapa.

O CEP que estamos acostumados hoje, todavia, é aquele que designa uma rua, uma praça ou ainda "o lado par do trecho da rua", etc. Esse tipo de CEP é chamado de *CEP comum* (tem sufixo na faixa de `001` a `899`). A coisa que ele designa é um "polígono de faces de quadra" (ver [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal#Entidades_geogr.C3.A1ficas_designadas_pelo_CEP)), que na ilustração abaixo corresponde a uma cor, 
[image]
(imaginar por ex. que o *CEP 12345-678* designa a cor azul)

Assim chegamos numa outra possível resposta... **Resposta-2**: Os *CEPs comuns* são sempre únicos, designando cada qual a sua "região de faces de quadra" no mapa.

Do [ponto de vista topológico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM), todavia, tem algo estranho:   as áreas da resposta-2 estão no interior da das áreas da resposta-1. Desse ponto de vista há sobreposição espacial entre CEPs diferentes, ou seja, existem dois CEPs designando a mesma coisa... Pode-se alegar que não há unicidade nos CEPs como um todo, apenas quando considerando apenas um tipo de CEP.

---

Há ainda os ''CEPs especiais'', que podem designar endereços já contemplados pelo ''CEP comum'', mas novamente temos que entender que o ''CEP especial'', quando designando uma entidade geográfica, é uma entidade no interior de um ''CEP comum''... Mas, enfim: pode-se eventualmente alegar que os CEPs especiais duplicam alguns dos comuns.